# Get selected date from python wx.lib.calendar

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

How do you make button which open calendar then selects date and closes it?
So far I managed just create calendars (I don't get why it always creates 2). But I couldn't figure out how to get selected date. I'm using pythonwx on Python 3.

```
class MyCalendar(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kargs)
        self.cal = CalendarCtrl(self, 10, wx.DateTime.Now())
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)



if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyCalendar(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

**EDIT**

adding py3 version

```
from wx.adv import CalendarCtrl, GenericCalendarCtrl, CalendarDateAttr

class MyCalendar(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kargs)
        self.cal = CalendarCtrl(self, 10, wx.DateTime.Now())
        self.cal.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_CALENDAR, self.OnDate)



    def OnDate(self,event):
        print (self.cal.GetDate())      
        wx.Window.Close(self)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import wx
import wx.adv
class MyCalendar(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kargs)
        self.cal = wx.adv.CalendarCtrl(self, 10, wx.DateTime.Now())
        self.cal.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_CALENDAR, self.OnDate)

    def OnDate(self,event):
        print(self.cal.GetDate())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyCalendar(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Now double click on a date.

I'll leave you to research creating a frame/panel and putting a button on it, to activate the calendar.

Answer (score 2):

This simple request is a bit more complicated than it first looks, as you have to wait for a result of a date selection, other than now, without over complicating it.
Putting it all in the same class would make life easier, as would using `wx.DatePickerCtrl`
For what it is worth, here is my attempt at answering your whole question.

```
import wx
import wx.calendar
import time
class MyCalendar(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, "Calendar",size=(300,300))
        self.Panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.cal = wx.calendar.CalendarCtrl(self.Panel, 10, wx.DateTime.Now())
        self.cal.Bind(wx.calendar.EVT_CALENDAR, self.OnDate)
        self.Show()

    def OnDate(self,event):
        self.Destroy()
        return self.cal.GetDate()

class Myframe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.Panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.Button = wx.Button(self.Panel, label="Calendar",size=(60,25),pos=(10,300))
        self.Selected = wx.TextCtrl(self.Panel, -1,"Selected Date",size=(300,25),pos=(10,50))
        self.Button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ShowCal)
        self.Show()

    def ShowCal(self,event):
        now = wx.DateTime.Now()
        now.SetHMS(0)
        self.Selected_date = MyCalendar(self.Panel)
        while self.Selected_date and self.Selected_date.cal.GetDate() == now:
            wx.Yield()
            time.sleep(0.1)
        try:
            self.Selected.SetValue(str(self.Selected_date.cal.GetDate()))
        except:
            self.Selected.SetValue("Nothing selected")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Myframe(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

I'm sure that there must be a more elegant way of achieving this and hopefully someone else will produce an answer but as you can see I have opted to wait in a `while` loop until a result other than `Now` is selected and `Now` has been adjusted to be midnight, today, as that is what Calendar returns.

Edit:
The answer is to use an `event`, which is fired by the calendar date selection (double clicking on a date)

```
import wx
import wx.adv
import datetime
import wx.lib.newevent
cal_event, EVT_CAL_EVENT = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()

class MyCalendar(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, "Calendar",size=(300,300))
        self.parent = parent
        self.Panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.cal = wx.adv.CalendarCtrl(self.Panel, 10, wx.DateTime.Now())
        self.cal.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_CALENDAR, self.OnDate)
        self.Show()

    def OnDate(self,event):
        evt = cal_event(data=self.cal.GetDate())
        wx.PostEvent(self, evt) #post EVT_CAL_EVENT

class Myframe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.Panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.Button = wx.Button(self.Panel, label="Calendar",size=(60,25),pos=(10,300))
        self.Selected = wx.TextCtrl(self.Panel, -1,"Selected Date",size=(300,25),pos=(10,50))
        self.Button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ShowCal)
        self.Show()

    def ShowCal(self,event):
        now = wx.DateTime.Now()
        now.SetHMS(0)
        self.Selected_date = MyCalendar(self)
        self.Selected_date.Bind(EVT_CAL_EVENT, self.GetCal)

    def GetCal(self,event):
        ymd = map(int, event.data.FormatISODate().split('-'))
        d = datetime.date(*ymd) # Convert to a datetime so we can use standard formatting
        self.Selected.SetValue(d.strftime("%a - %d/%m/%Y"))
        self.Selected_date.Destroy()
        del self.Selected_date

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Myframe(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

This provides the date as "Weekday name - dd/mm/yyyy" e.g. Tue - 23/02/2021